# What circumstances could cause IE8 to occasionally not load a script?

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-8

I've been troubleshooting an HTML page where one dynamically inserted `<script>` fails to load itself and run its code only *every few times the page is visited.*

However, not being extremely experienced in debugging, I've run out of places to look, or things to check or watch out for.

Could anyone suggest what circumstances or reasons could cause IE8, but *not* IE9, to "forget" to run a dynamically inserted, external javascript file *only every few visits?*

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

As requested, here is a simplified collection of snippets the way I have them executing:

1. CMS template loads page with Prototype.js in the `<head>` - I cannot modify the head.
2. HTML just inside `<body>` tag is parsed by browser:

   ```
   <!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
       /* THE SCRIPT BELOW IS THE ONE RANDOMLY BEING DROPPED BY IE7/8 */
       <script src="/file_uploads/selectivizr.js"></script> 
   <![endif]-->
   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
       /* THESE SCRIPTS BELOW ALWAYS WORK, AND ARE NEVER DROPPED */
       <script src="/file_uploads/html5.js"></script>
       <script src="/file_uploads/iemq.js"></script>
   <![endif]-->
   ```
3. Page loads normally, `<script>` just before `</body>` is executed:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
           var myContent = document.getElementById('myContent').innerHTML;
           document.body.innerHTML = myContent; // FYI: Excludes this script
           document.stopObserving("dom:loaded");
       });
   </script>
   ```

4: Body content has now been replaced with what is required for responsive layout to work.

NOTE: We are unable to modify the `<head>` nor anything outside of the `<body>`.

NOTE: **selectivizr.js** uses AJAX to reload all external CSS stylesheets being used on the page, and post-processes the DOM.

Comment: How do you add that script? Can we see the code?

Comment: You can add `javascript:alert('script loading')` before it loads, and `javascript:alert('script finished loading')` after to confirm that the script actually starts and finishes loading.  If you add more alerts within the script itself, you can debug that way to see where it's failing.

Comment: @ime-vidas Just added context/example.

Answer (score 0):

A network problem between the browser and your server. Happens all the time to me. I get pages where the css file doesn't load and the page is horribly messy as a result.